# How to pass props to component inside function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I try to pass props to Component inside the function it always returns "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions".

```
handleComponent(){
     <Component getid={value} />
}
```

why is this happening and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call component in return of render in compoennt like this

```
 render(){
     return(
       <Component getid={value}/>
     )
    }
```

Comment: @user12551649 if this does ans of your que than please do it as marked so, can closed this que .

Answer (score 1):

You used `handleComponent` in render function (or in return if you use functional component), I gues, so `handleComponent` need to return a piece of JSX code.Your `handleComponent` don't have return keyword so it return undefined, that's why you get that error.
Try the following code:

```js
handleComponent(){
     return <Component getid={value} />
}
```